# Paste into text area

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I tried to make my day easier making a program that will register my self into card game tournaments via selenium webdriver. I am beginner so I was thrilled even though it was just basics aka click here, confirm this, write that but at the end I ran into a problem that I am having trouble solving.

At the end you need to submit decks via deck code. The sendKeys function? (not sure if thats the correct wording) does not work since it actually needs to be pasted into the text area. Whenever you try to "just" write into the box it says its invalid deck code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"react-root\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/textarea")).click();

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\\\"react-root\\\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/textarea")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL + "v"));
```

I went with this, first line just clicking in to the text area and then trying to paste it in (while I copied the deck code manually, not sure how I will solve this since I need to paste 3 different ones, but that is issue for the future) but the code just wont paste and I have no idea where is the catch. I tried the paste function in different text area with the same settings meaning I have something copied in my clipboard and it worked just fine.

Example of the deck code is

```
" AAECAZICCiT3A94FrtICv/IC9fwC2KAD+KED9KID/KMDCkBWX/4BxAapogPIogPcogPvogPZqQMA "
```

I hope I provided everything I should have otherwise let me know and I will gladly post more :) Thanks in advance and I hope someone can help me

Comment: Just sendKeys("your string") to textarea instead of sendKeys(CONTROL+V)

Comment: 1.  please add the html structure of textarea. 2. deck code you provided in the post has the same you pasted in text area? if yes then it has trailing space before and after 3. is the same deck working when you tried manually? 4. is the text area inside the iframe? 5. provide the code trials and errors you getting,  6. please read the [mcve] and post questions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This might not work because I don't see you explicitly copying the deck code, as you mentioned you did it manually. I also modified your example to not use Keys.chord, as you might not need them here.

To copy the element:

```
deckCodeWebElement = driver.findElement(locatorToFindDeckCode);

deckCodeWebElement.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'a')
time.sleep(1)
deckCodeWebElement.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'c')
```

Then, to paste:

```
deckCodeWebElementToPaste = driver.findElement(locatorToFindDeckCodeToPaste);

deckCodeWebElementToPaste.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+'v')
```

On another note, I recommend shortening your XPaths to relative notation, as the absolute notation you are using is very brittle and breaks very easy. You want to find elements irrespective of their location in the DOM tree.

You can change this:

`//*[@id=\\\"react-root\\\"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/textarea`

to just this:

`//textarea`

You may need to query on something like ID, class, or name if there are multiple `textarea` elements, but there is no need to start at the root node and use `div[2]` and `div[4]` unless absolutely necessary.